# str_count from one dataframe into another

Tags: r, stringr

I am relatively new R user and I have a query.
I have 2 dataframes as shown below:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  OrderNo = c("ORD-34212", "ORD-12252", "ORD-78564", "ORD-56438",
          "ORD-13198", "ORD-12258", "ORD-34567"),
  Status = c("Delivered", "Not delivered", "Not delivered",
         "Delivered", "Not delivered", "Delivered", "Delivered"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

df2 <- data.frame(
  Description = c("ORD-34212 was delivered but not ORD-12252", "ORD-78564 was placed on 21/2/2018",
              "my order is ORD-56438", "ORD-56438 and ORD-12258", "ORD-34212 is from Europe"),
  DB = c("updated", "updated", "not updated", "not updated", "updated"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

I want to be able to count the occurrences of each "OrderNo" mentioned in df1 from the column "Description" in df2. I know I have to use **str_count** but I am unable to generate the logic for the same.

I want the output df1 to look like this with count and a flag if orderno was found:
[image]

Can you please help out here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `df1$Count <- colSums(sapply(df1$OrderNo, function(x) str_count(df2$Description, x))); df1$FoundinSecondDF <- df1$Count > 0`

Comment: @LAP Thanks for your comment. I will check it out asap!

Answer (score 2):

A dplyr solution:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(Count = sum(grepl(OrderNo,df2$Description)), FoundInSecondDF = any(grepl(OrderNo,df2$Description)))
# Source: local data frame [7 x 4]
# Groups: <by row>
# 
# A tibble: 7 x 4
#   OrderNo   Status        Count FoundInSecondDF
#   <chr>     <chr>         <int> <lgl>          
# 1 ORD-34212 Delivered         2 T              
# 2 ORD-12252 Not delivered     1 T              
# 3 ORD-78564 Not delivered     1 T              
# 4 ORD-56438 Delivered         2 T              
# 5 ORD-13198 Not delivered     0 F              
# 6 ORD-12258 Delivered         1 T              
# 7 ORD-34567 Delivered         0 F
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will check it out asap!